# Finite range operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

This theorem is from Rudin book which he says that obvious, but I'm quite confused how to prove it completely. Hope someone can help me clarify.

> > Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces, If $T \in B(X,Y)$ and dim $R(T) \lt \infty$, then $T$ is compact

Because dim $R(T) \lt \infty$, $R(T)$ is closed in $Y$. Then $R(T)$ is complete because $Y$ is complete. Following from open mapping theorem, we conclude that $T$ is an open mapping from $X$ onto $R(T)$. Because $\overline{T(U)}$ is closed, we need to prove that it is bounded. But $U$ is bounded, then $T(U)$ is bounded, so $\overline{T(U)}$ is bounded. Therefore $\overline{T(U)}$ is compact (without using dim $R(T) \lt \infty$). So what did I do wrong? Where to use the statement dim $R(T) \lt \infty$. Thanks

Comment: the first statement in your argument does seem to use the finite dimension of $R(T)$ to assure us that it is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the fact that the range is finite dimensional to conclude that it is closed. In general it may not be closed! I would prove it like this:

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in the unit ball of $X$. Then $T(x_n)$ is bounded: For any $n\in \Bbb{N}$, we have 
$$\|T(x_n)\| \leq \|T\| \|x_n\| \leq M$$

for some constant $M$ because $T$ is bounded and $\{x_n\}$ is in the unit ball. Furthermore $T(x_n)$ is contained in a finite dimensional subspace. Now use the fact that a bounded sequence in a finite dimensional complete normed vector space has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Now forget about dim $R(T) \lt \infty$. To prove that $T$ is compact, we must prove that $\overline{T(U)}$ is compact, which means closed and bounded. Obviously, it's closed. And using the statement I make in the question to prove its boundedness, we conclude that $\overline{T(U)}$ is compact, so $T$ is compact??? So what's wrong in my proof? Can you please explain for me? Thanks

Comment: @leducquang You're making one very big mistake: A closed, bounded subset need not be compact!

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I check it again, it's only true for finite dimensional normed space. Thanks so much.

Comment: And one more thing, in Walter book, every finite subspace with finite dimension is closed. So for sure, $R(T)$ is a subspace, and from the assumption, is finite dimensional. So why we can't conclude that $R(T)$ is closed?